# Replaces lines in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to find and replace two lines in SNMP file, but the result is not like I want.

Ansible skipped the first line and added two new lines.
This is part of my playbook:

```
- name: configure the snmpd set to private
  become: true
  lineinfile:
    path: "/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf"
    regexp: '^#*\srocommunity.*'
    line: |
      rocommunity private  default    -V systemonly
      rocommunity6 private  default    -V systemonly
    backrefs: yes
  register: file_updated
```

Playbook Result:

```
rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
rocommunity private  default    -V systemonly
rocommunity6 private  default    -V systemonly
```

---

Desired result:

```
 rocommunity private  default    -V systemonly
 rocommunity6 private  default    -V systemonly
```

---

original file:

```
    ###############################################################################
#
#  ACCESS CONTROL
#

                                                 #  system + hrSystem groups only
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   systemonly  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1

                                                 #  Full access from the local host
#rocommunity public  localhost
                                                 #  Default access to basic system info
 rocommunity public  default    -V systemonly
                                                 #  rocommunity6 is for IPv6
 rocommunity6 public  default   -V systemonly

                                                 #  Full access from an example network
                                                 #     Adjust this network address to match your local
                                                 #     settings, change the community string,
                                                 #     and check the 'agentAddress' setting above
#rocommunity secret  10.0.0.0/16

                                                 #  Full read-only access for SNMPv3
 rouser   authOnlyUser
                                                 #  Full write access for encrypted requests
                                                 #     Remember to activate the 'createUser' lines above
#rwuser   authPrivUser   priv
#  It's no longer typically necessary to use the full 'com2sec/group/access' configuration
#  r[ow]user and r[ow]community, together with suitable views, should cover most requirements



###############################################################################
```

Comment: how does the file look like before the replacement? Always put sample input and expected output(what you consider to be desired) in the question if possible.

Comment: I think the problem is from the regexp, but as said in the previous comment, we need more details to be able to help you

Comment: I just updated the post. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `blockinfile` with `insertafter` to add multiple lines in place of single line

Comment: I found a solution, I used replace module instead.